# Uploading File of size < 250KB to Firebase with Progressbar in android

Tags: android, firebase, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload small image files of size 60KB - 200KB to Firebase Storage. Everything is fine. The problem here is the Progress bar,it just not updating.

According to Frank-Van-Puffelen (https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) : Firebase upload progress fires at 250 KB of chunks. So if file size is less than 250KB then Progress bar will jump 0 to 100% . So how to deal with this. How to show Progressbar updates.

Comment: The only way is to write your own Firebase SDK on top of REST API, this way you can track progress on each packet sent. But it's hard. Better send a request feature in Firebase Console

Comment: Do you know any other easy workaround ?

Comment: yeah, decompile firebase sdk, modify and compile back. Man, it's just waste of time, or you are living in place where the only internet connection is GPRS?

Comment: What on earth  Internet Connection speed has anything to do with the Progress Update ? Are you even understanding my Question man?

Comment: 250kb uploads in less than half of second. If you have such small files you don't need progress view at all

Comment: My app calls a method when upload hits  50% progress. So without the progress bar how im suppose to do it  ?

Comment: if you provide full problem description it will be easier to suggest you an workaround

Answer (score 2):

if you want to add method which call on only upload 50% complete you can do it by below code but if you want to show a progress bar i think there is nothing to help because you no function for this in `Firebase` as chunk size is 250kb
yes you can trigger a method on 50% butt let me tell your file will upload 100% you cannot stop from uploading it i per my knowledge

code is below

```
downloadingTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(final FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progressSize = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())
                                    / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

if(progressSize==50){your method;}});
```